# Header section has more than 10240 bytes (maybe it is not properly terminated)

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, jira-rest-api

I'm using NodeJs to try to upload an attachment to a Jira Issue via the Jira Rest API.

The api expects multipart/form-data so this is how I'm calling it in Node:

```
function uploadAttachments(supportFormData, callback) {
    const url =
      'https://somewhere.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/' +
      supportFormData.issueId +
      '/attachments';

    var options = {
      url: url,
      headers: {
        Authorization: { user: username, password: password },
        'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck'
      }
    };

    var r = request.post(options, function(err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        callback(false);
      } else {
        console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
        callback(false);
      }
    });

    var form = r.form();
    form.append('file', supportFormData.attachments[0].contents, {
      filename: supportFormData.attachments[0].fileName,
      contentType: supportFormData.attachments[0].contents
    });
  }
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Header section
>   has more than 10240 bytes (maybe it is not properly terminated)

The "supportFormData.attachments[0].contents" is ofType Buffer.

Any suggestions as to what could be causing this error?

Comment: is it basic auth? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization.

Comment: Yes, basic auth

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue and it turns out JIRA (or Java) requires `\r\n` as new line character. After I changed `\n` to `\r\n` my requests went through without problem.

Comment: it's really shame the multipart fails in case of using only \n

Answer (score 0):

If its a basic auth change options object to

```js
let auth = new Buffer(`${username}:${password}`).toString('base64');
var options = {
      url: url,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Basic ${auth}`,
        'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck'
      }
    };
```

Comment: Changed to this, same error though. BTW `new Buffer` should now be `Buffer.from`